# Function evaluation of logarithm of normal PDF differs from Python

Tags: gnuplot

I plotted the logarithm of the pdf of the normal distribution.
Now i want to plot linear approximations of this function for different x-values (x=3). The problem is, that the returned values are not the expected ones.

```
set xrange[-4:4]

f(x) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*2**2) * exp(-x**2/(2*2**2))
g(x) = log(f(x))
h(x) = -0.5 * log(2*pi*2**2) - x**2/(2*2**2)

print(f(3))
print(g(3))
print(h(3))


 plot h(x) with lines, \
      h(3) with lines, \
      # expected output
      -2.737085713764618 with lines
```

I expect h(3) = -2.737085713764618, but get h(3) = -2.61208571376462 from gnuplot. I assume i am making a stupid mistake here. It would be great if someone could explain to me what is happening here.

Comment: gnuplot uses integer division, e.g. 2/3 = 0, which is a malicious pitfall in gnuplot if you don't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot uses integer division if the arguments are integers.  To force floating point division you must provide real arguments.

```
f(x) = 1.0/sqrt(2*pi*2**2) * exp(-x**2/(2.0*2**2))
g(x) = log(f(x))
h(x) = -0.5 * log(2*pi*2**2) - x**2/(2.0*2**2)

print h(3.0)
-2.73708571376462
```